# Show hidden section by javascript function

Tags: javascript, css, html, dom

I have the `<h1>` tag in my HTML body and I want it to react to each time a user clicks on it according to the conditions I have defined in a javascript function called `ShowIt()`. The first click will show the hidden section and second click to re-hide it, toggling back and forth. However, I can't get it to work.

#### CSS:

```
*{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}

header,section,nav,aside,footer{
    display: block;
}

.wrapper{
    position: relative;
    width: 1000px;
    height: 4000px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

#hid{
    background-color: #FF9;
    color: #000;
    font-size: 25px;
    font-family: Arial;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 1200px;
    display:none;
}

h1{
    cursor: pointer;
    color: #000;
    font-size: 25px;
    font-family: Arial;
    position: absolute;
    top: 1150px;
}
```

#### HTML & JS:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="includes/style.css">
        <script src="includes/script.js"></script>
        <title>Some JS</title>

        <script>
            window.onload=function(){

                function ShowIt(){
                    var obj = document.getElementById("hid");
                    if(obj.style.display == "block")
                            obj.style.display = "none";
                    else
                            obj.style.display = "block";
                };
            }
        </script>

    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="wrapper">
            <section id="hid">hidden layer</section>
            <h1 onclick="ShowIt">click here</h1>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your function should be declared outside the `window.onload` other wise you'll get scope issues.

Some JS

```
    <script>
       function ShowIt(){
          var obj = document.getElementById("hid");
          if(obj.style.display == "block")
             obj.style.display = "none";
          else
             obj.style.display = "block";
       };
    </script>

</head>
<body>
    <div class="wrapper">
        <section id="hid">hidden layer</section>
        <h1 onclick="ShowIt()">click here</h1>
    </div>
</body>
```

And to call that function you need to do: `ShowIt()`

Comment: Thank you, now it's OK, though there shouldn't be a problem if I define window.onload=function(){} and then other functions not inside the scope of the above right?

Comment: no, when you do that, the scope of the function is just inside the {}

Comment: @user2350095, did you see the fiddle?

Answer (score 2):

you have define `ShowIt` function inside `window.onload` function, this wont work because socpe of `ShowIt` is not global.

```
 <script>

                function ShowIt(){
                    var obj = document.getElementById("hid");
                    if(obj.style.display == "block")
                            obj.style.display = "none";
                    else
                            obj.style.display = "block";
                };

        </script>



 <div class="wrapper">
            <section id="hid">hidden layer</section>
            <h1 onclick="ShowIt()">click here</h1>
        </div>
```